# Can someone explain these floating point values for this SVM binary file?

Tags: file, binary, svm, libsvm

I am working with the news20.binary file found here at this site. https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary.html

this is a pre-generated binary file to be used with LibSVM libraries. I have a small example of the binary file below.  My question is that I don't understand how the floating point values were generated. For example, notice the index:value pairs and how the value is the same across the row. The next row has repeated index values, but the paired value is unique here, but also repeats regardless of the index value across the row. Here is a small subset of what LibSVM has for their binary file.

```
-1 1:0.016563 2:0.016563 3:0.016563 4:0.016563 5:0.016563 6:0.016563 7:0.016563
-1 1:0.013067 2:0.013067 3:0.013067 5:0.013067 6:0.013067 9:0.013067 13:0.013067
-1 40:0.028421 54:0.028421 75:0.028421 81:0.028421 89:0.028421 97:0.028421 102:0.028421
-1 40:0.048057 57:0.048057 75:0.048057 97:0.048057 102:0.048057 103:0.048057 114:0.048057
-1 40:0.084515 75:0.084515 97:0.084515 103:0.084515 114:0.084515 120:0.084515 171:0.084515
-1 9:0.028352 32:0.028352 40:0.028352 54:0.028352 57:0.028352 75:0.028352 81:0.028352
-1 9:0.090167 75:0.090167 97:0.090167 102:0.090167 103:0.090167 114:0.090167 149:0.090167
-1 40:0.047458 75:0.047458 89:0.047458 97:0.047458 103:0.047458 114:0.047458 149:0.047458
-1 40:0.031976 48:0.031976 75:0.031976 81:0.031976 89:0.031976 97:0.031976 102:0.031976
```

I realize that scaling and normalization is probably happening but in what sense? I thought perhaps it was as simple as getting the feature_max value at each index, as well as the feature_min value. Then scaling these extreme values down to a value between 0 and 1. This is what my binary file appears as now.

```
6:1.000000 68:0.000000 83:0.392857 94:0.073786 334:1.000000 463:1.000000 625:1.000000
63:0.613432 119:0.595636 121:0.357801 325:0.466867 477:1.000000 664:0.466867 892:0.300000
15:0.000000 64:0.553846 94:0.089619 150:1.000000 356:1.000000 418:1.000000 602:1.000000
76:1.000000 94:0.794175 171:0.925523 576:1.000000 581:1.000000 616:0.923810 698:1.000000 1229:1.000000                      
15:0.857143 36:0.778842 94:0.191401 308:1.000000 382:0.122203 617:0.266600 858:0.576355
63:0.350350 94:0.142395 296:1.000000 325:0.585341 718:1.000000 785:0.269692 932:0.693694
313:0.279469 790:0.311258 1016:1.000000 1028:1.000000 1239:1.000000 1541:1.000000 1708:1.000000
9:0.402892 53:1.000000 60:0.567273 94:0.217864 592:1.000000 615:0.246701 663:0.738462
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [description](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary.html#news20.binary) of news20.binary,

> Preprocessing: Each instance has unit length.

e.g. for the first instance, all 3646 features are 0.016563, so 1=3646*(0.016563)^2

According to [this paper](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume6/keerthi05a/keerthi05a.pdf), news20.binary originally comes from the text data [UCI Twenty Newsgroups](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Twenty+Newsgroups) and is generated by [TFIDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) which is a common way to deal with text-data.

As a result, news20.binary has binary features before scaling, and for a single instance, its features are all the same.

Comment: Thanks! Let me spend a little time digesting your contributions and will get back shortly.